# Prototype instance like cat c = new animal();?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

I am newbie to Javascript and recently, I faced this question and am curious to know the answer.

```
function animal(){
  // some bse code
}


function cat(){
  //some cat code
}

// I know this syntax and works well
cat.prototype= new animal;
```

and I would like to know the below syntax is correct?

```
cat c = new animal;
```

Is it possible in javascript?

(sorry! If the question exists.)

Comment: var c = new cat(); much better!

Comment: @ius no! I would like to know, cat c and cat.prototype are equal?

Comment: Excellent answer by TJ. If you would like to know more about prototype and inheriting you may find some useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. In JavaScript you can't declare the type of a variable. The type of a variable is the type of its current value, so

```
var c = new animal(); //correct
```

but

```
cat c = new animal(); //parse error.
```

Answer (score 7):

> and I would like to know the below syntax is correct?
>
> `cat c = new animal;`

No, JavaScript variables are always loosely typed, so you don't declare types for them, you just declare them with `var` (and in ES6, `let`).

So:

```
var c = new animal;
```

---

Side note #1: In JavaScript, the *overwhelming* convention is to use an initial capital letter for functions that are intended to be used as constructor functions (e.g., via the `new` keyword). E.g., `Animal` and `Cat`, not `animal` and `cat`.

---

Side note #2: About this:

```
// I know this syntax and works well
cat.prototype= new animal;
```

That's a common, but poor, practice. Here's how to do that correctly:

```
cat.prototype = Object.create(animal.prototype);
cat.prototype.constructor = cat;
```

...and then in `cat`, as the first thing:

```
animal.call(this);
```

Complete example with updated capitalization:

```
function Animal() {
}

function Cat() {
    Animal.call(this);

    // ...add Cat-level initialization here
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
```

---

About `Object.create`: It's an ES5 function that creates an object with a specific underlying prototype. The proper ES5 version takes two arguments, and what it does with the second argument cannot be shimmed on older browsers. But for what we're doing, we only need the first argument, which *can* be shimmed on older browsers:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw "Object.create shims cannot implement the second argument.";
        }

        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = proto;

        return new ctor();
    };
}
```

---

So why is `Cat.prototype = new Animal;` poor practice? Well, what if `Animal` takes per-instance arguments? Consider:

```
function Animal(age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

What would we give for `age` in the `Cat.prototype = new Animal(???);` line?

Answer: We don't. We shouldn't *call* `Animal`, which is a constructor function for instances, until we're constructing an instance. Instead, we create a new object for the `Cat.prototype` property, and give that new object `Animal.prototype` as its prototype.

Complete example:

```
function Animal(age) {
    this.age = age;
}
function Cat(age, color) {
    Animal.call(this, age);
    this.color = color;
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

var c = new Cat(14, "Tabby");
```

Comment: In the complete example, is actually needed to put Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;? I don't get why.

Comment: @ius: The `constructor` property is a bit of an oddity: It's defined for the objects engines create for functions ([§13.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)) and basically mentioned nowhere else. The `Foo.prototype` object engines create for `function Foo() { }` will have a `constructor` prop referring to `Foo`. In theory this prop it would be useful for cloning object graphs, but there are lots of edge cases there. I always do it when replacing a function's `prototype` obj because that's what the spec defines, and otherwise `constructor` points to the wrong function.

Comment: Oh, that's new for me! I've been trying a bit and you are right. Thanks!